# JSONArray strange behavior for different API Versions

Tags: android

I have a problem with JSONArray. My JSONArray works on API 22 but not on a device with API less than 22.
When I change my compile sdk I get tons of errors.
Is there any solution for this strange behavior. I can't explain it...
This is the JSON:

```
{"2":"[{\"id\":\"3\",\"value\":\"1.15\",\"name\":\"Knobi\"}, Dressing]","1":"[{\"id\":\"1\",\"value\":\"0.00\",\"name\":\"Scharf\"}, Soße, {\"id\":\"2\",\"value\":\"1.00\",\"name\":\"Tzatziki\"}, Soße]"}

if(addonsJSON != null)
{
    Iterator<String> iterator = addonsJSON.keys();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        String theKey = iterator.next();
        System.out.println(addonsJSON.get(theKey));
        JSONArray values = addonsJSON.getJSONArray(theKey);
        for (int j = 0; j < values.length(); j+=2)
        {
            JSONObject vals = new JSONObject(values.getString(j));

            CartChild cartChild = new CartChild();
            cartChild.name = vals.getString("name");
            cartChild.price = vals.getString("value");
            itemtotal += Float.parseFloat(vals.getString("value"));

            childsList.add(cartChild);
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Post some code if you want help, otherwise your post is likely to be closed.

Comment: your JSON is invalid, place it in a JSON-validator

Comment: Edited my answer. I modified the JSON here in Stackoverflow. This is the real one

Answer (score 0):

your json is **not a valid** json text. You can't iterate over invalid json

modify it like that

```
{
    "1": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "value": "0.00",
            "name": "Scharf"
        },
        "Soße",
        {
            "id": "2",
            "value": "1.00",
            "name": "Tzatziki"
        },
        "Soße"
    ],
    "2": [
        {
            "id": "3",
            "value": "1.15",
            "name": "Knobi"
        },
        "Dressing"
    ]
}
```

compare your json and mine on http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Edited my Question. I modified my JSOn here in stackoverflow. Now this is the real one from the addonsJSON variable

Comment: still it is not valid. i dont know how Android L handle it but you must moditfy your json

Comment: Ok I see. Strange. JSONLint tells me that the JSON is valid.

Comment: you are trying to handle your elements like string. yes it is valid but after "1": or "2": part, inner id, value and name are in same element. They are not seperated

Comment: Yeah beacuse I convert the HashMap to JSONObject and than save it as a String in SugarORM. And then convert it from string to jsonobject. maybe this is the bug? SugarORM can't save HashMaps

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I convert the HashMap to a `JSONObject`. After that I saved my `JSONObject` as a String to SugarORM. The convertion was the fault!
So I tried it with GSON. Now it works.

So just use this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(hashmap);
```